# What is this plant with thorns on bottom of leave

Tags: identification, weeds

This plant has sprung up in a few places. Im not sure if its a weed and should be pulled or left alone. It has thorns growing  under the leaf down the spine.[image: spikes on leave]

Heres another pick i thought primula at first but the leaves seem too long.

Im in USDA 8,9.

After a little digging. Im actually starting to think its a Teasler.I'll wait until it flowers and post answer if it is.
[image: leaf size]

Comment: Please send a few more pictures as well as more information.  Is this out in your garden?  Your landscape? In the shade?  What is your zone?  USDA?

Comment: A  photo  of the whole plant for proper ID is essential...

Answer (score 2):

This looks like Primula spp.  These tiny hairs can be very irritating to those that are sensitive to primula.  Primrose.  A little perennial people plant and forget and find it the next year.  Don't pull it out...it should have flowers soon. [primula](https://tse4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.maEIy1UN6WzqGtluMCEbLwHaFj&pid=15.1&P=0&w=242&h=183)